# iOS UIProgressView with 2+ colors

Tags: ios, uiprogressview, diskspace

I'm developing an iOS app to show total disk space, available disk space and disk space usage by the app itself. I've successfully showed the total disk space and available disk space in UIProgressView but I need to show the app usage space in the used space as well.

What will be the option to show the app usage space within the used space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could position a second `UIProgressView` over top of the first, making its trackTintColor transparent and setting its progress to the smaller of the two values you want to display.

Comment: I've implemented your idea and got the result but in terms of making background transparent we need to set trackTintColor to transparent. I've updated your answer. Thanks